# Regress two related correlation samples against age?

Tags: regression, correlation

I'm relatively new to stats and I was wondering if there was a way for me to regress two correlation samples against age. I understand it makes no sense to have a correlation **and** regression, it's one or the other, but hopefully my explanation will clarify what I mean.

I conducted a study whereby in condition 1, participants had to write down (from 1-10) how angry they deemed a person to be judging by the sound of their footsteps. The footsteps increased by 2dB each time (in total, 9 clips were played from 60dB to 76dB).
In the second condition, the footsteps were accompanied by a point-light display of a person walking, with the speed of the video getting faster by 80 milliseconds each time from 1320ms to 680ms. So, when the dB was 60, the ms was 1320 and as dB increased, ms got less (faster).

I have assembled the data in SPSS but I was wanting to regress it against age, either as two separate samples or comparing these two conditions together. However, I am completely lost. I want to see if age influenced the anger rating that participants gave to the footsteps audio (condition 1) and the footsteps x point-light display (condition 2).

But I don't know how to do this as the anger ratings also need to remain with the dB for which they were recorded. What I mean by this is that I have three columns in SPSS. One has the anger rating that participants gave. The second has the dB that each anger rating in the first column corresponds to. The third has the age for each participant. Please could anyone suggest how I could regress the data against age whilst still keeping the anger rating assigned to the relevant dB? Will I need to separate the two conditions, then look at one of these conditions and separate all of the data into the relevant dB (60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76), then conduct a regression against age for each individual dB? Or is there an easier way to do this?

Many thanks in advance and sorry if I have not provided enough information, please let me know if I need to clarify anything!

Comment: Your question dips down into highly-specific dB and ms descriptions before it states how many subjects in each group rated the clips(?).  Also, how many people were used for clip generation for each condition? -- i.e., the number of raters is usually different from the number of subjects from which measurements were obtained.   Next, how many variables (features) were there?  This could very well be an "interrator agreement" question, that's based on the kappa statistic.